# SQL many-to-one join using two foreign keys

Tags: sql, qgis, spatialite

I have two tables (Table A & Table B) that I have in a database (SpatiaLite database).  I would like to join all the entries in Table A with Table B using two foreign keys (TableA.Location & TableB.LSD, TableA.LICENCE_NO & TableB.Licence_No); however, there will be multiple INCIDEN_NO entries in Table A that match up with the joined rows in Table B.

Since there will be many INCIDEN_NO entries associated with the Licence_No in Table B, I would like to evenly distribute the INCIDEN_NO entries among all the LIC_LI_NO entries in Table B that align with the foreign keys.  The rows from Table A can be randomly assigned to each LIC_LI_NO in Table B randomly and in no particular order.

I cannot seem to find a SQL expression for this operation, which has really stumped me for weeks.

[image: picture of the join and potential output table]

Comment: Please provide your data as tabular text. This tiny image is unreadable.

Comment: From your data is not clear which table is the parent one and which one is the children table. The keys seems to be repeated in both tables; therefore, they are not "keys".

Comment: Sorry about the image, however, if you right click the picture and open in a new window one can zoom in on it to make it readable.  I am unsure about the parent table and child table question.  I just thought that columns with unique values to that row would be the key.  These tables are attribute tables imported into a SpatiaLite database called Pipe_inc.sqlite.  I am very new to databases and SQL.

Comment: What is the purpose of randomizing the license information? Is this about creating test data or something? Is this not good enough as test data already?

Comment: The Licence_No is for a whole pipeline, but the LIC_LI_NO is for each segment of the pipeline.  The data in Table A represents incidents (INCIDEN_NO) for each LIC_LI_NO over time, but the LIC_LI_NO for each INCIDEN_NO is not correct for the segment at each grid square location (LOCATION).  Table B is the midpoint of each pipeline in each grid square (400 m x 400 m).  The Licence_No  for the pipeline(s) in each grid sq is correct but there are potentially an n-number of pipelines with the same Licence_No.  I want to assign the incidents in Table A randomly among the midpoints of each LIC_LI_NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match the rows up randomly with something like this:

```
with B as (
    select row_number() over () as rn, lic_li_no
    from B
), A as (
    select abs(random()) % cntb + 1 as randnum, a.*
    from A cross apply (select count(*) as cntb from B) b
)
select *
from A inner join B on A.randnum = B.rn;
```

You could also generate the cross product and keep random rows. I tried this query out on SQLite but it didn't seem to work as I expected:

```
select * from A cross join B where abs(random()) % 20 = 1
```

That said, I don't understand the purpose behind all this and it's certainly not a common thing to do in a database.